# Как добавить модуль в файл с расширением exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция

Есть код, который я хочу из py преобразовать в exe. Делаю это с помощью PyInstaller через CMD. Но созданный файл не запускается, пишет вот такое:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "pyglet".
Как добавить этот модуль в файл с расширением exe.

```
import pyglet
import time
delay = 10000

time.sleep(delay)
song = pyglet.media.load('sound.mp3')
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()


time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы писали код в виртуальном окружении, в котором импортировали этот модуль. 
Попробуйте выполнить в cmd эту команду и попытаться ещё раз: 
`pip install pyglet`

Comment: В cmd так же установлен этот модуль. Но оно всё равно не работает((

Comment: Попробуйте `pip3 install pyglet`. По всей видимости команда, которую я дал в ответе установила версию модуля для второго питона.

Comment: Пишет что этот модуль уже установлен. Не думаю что pip3 что-то бы исправил. Правда не знаю в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Только что проверил ваш пример у себя - всё в порядке. Проверьте путь к модулю `pyglet` и `pyinstaller` командой `pip show *module_name*`, пути совпадают?

Comment: не совпадает только Requires:

Answer (score 0):

В итоге всё просто. Нужно перекинуть файл музыки в папку dist!!!

Answer (score 0):

попробуй инсталировать модуль

```
python -m pip3 install pyglet
```

Если модуль будет уже установлен - удалите модуль и повторите действие.